# Altbeacon and iBeacon library queries

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am new to developing this technology.I am struggling to whether to use the old library or the now one. As I see the older library code I can understand some of it but when I tried to transfer to newer version of library, I encounter problems and I have been looking for answer lately but no luck with it.

1. First, at the older version there is a function that you can get `getProximity` but I can't find by new.
2. Secondly, to get the beacon's name, at the older version, you can use `getProximityUUID` where at the newer library, `getId1` can be printed out as string?
3. Finally, this may seemed asked by many people, but please tell me. Should I specify an unique uuid at beginning  so that it can detect a specific uuid?

I am using android to develop. These are the questions that is in my mind for long time.. If possible please help me out these questions, anything would be great help that I appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solutions for each of these:

1. In the [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), `beacon.getProximity()` has been removed.  Instead you can use `beacon.getDistance()`, which gives you an estimated distance in meters.  If the distance is < 1.0, consider it "immediate proximity", if it is 1.0-3.0, consider it "near proximity" and if it is > 3.0, consider it "far proximity".
2. To get the ProximityUUID as a string, you can use `beacon.getId1().toString()`
3. It depends on your use case whether you want to look for all beacons or only one with a specific UUID.  There is no right answer.  If all of the beacons you care about have the same UUID, you should probably use a UUID filter so you only see your own beacons.

Comment: and due to my low reputation, I am unable to give you thumb up.  Your answer is giving me ideas of what I should do. Thank you